# How can I disable Default Account teams

Tags: user-record

I am looking to disable Default Account Teams. I was wondering if it could be done out of the box.  I have looked into removing the related list but that is not possible since it doesn't give me the option.  Would this be possible with code?

Comment: Does this help http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/accountteam_default.htm Should be possible to delete default account team members.

Comment: I am thinking of turning off the default account team functionality entirely to stop users from adding members to their default team.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely disable Account Teams by navigating to

Your Name > Setup > Customize > Accounts > Account Teams
Click Enable Account Teams or Disable Account Teams.

Resources :
https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_accountteams.htm
http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/accountteam_default.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the automatic application of default account teams on a per-user basis via the checkbox when you edit the account team named 'Automatically add my default account team to accounts that I create or accounts that are transferred to me'.

If you want to remove account team members from an account you can use code similar to the following:

```
List<AccountTeamMember> members=[SELECT Id, UserId, AccountId FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE  AccountId = :accId]);

delete members;
```

I guess the difficulty comes if you only want to remove the default account team but allow people to be added to that account team.  In that case you'd probably need to interrogate the UserAccountTeamMember records associated with the user that owns the account, but you'd still have a good chance of false positives.  Maybe only remove the account team members if the list exactly matches that of the users default account team?